# Generic term for a thing that is versioned

Tags: generic-term

Lots of things can have versions, where a version is an updated iteration of the thing, and the more recent iteration is considered to be a replacement of the former iterations, such that at any time at most one version is considered "current."  For example:

- Software (Windows 7, Windows 8, etc.)
- Books (4th ed. 5th ed., etc)
- Cars (MY 2013, MY 2014, etc.)

Is there a generic term for "a thing that can be versioned"?

Is there a better term than "version," the way I define it above?

Comment: Maybe I'm missing your intent, but revision seems to cover it.

Comment: I think you'll end up appending an adjective like mutable, changeable, fixable to thing.   Which is sort of why variable and constant became nouns...   Perhaps these are mutables.

Comment: Could you provide an example of a sentence in which you'd use this word? *Software, books ,and cars are **versionable***.

Comment: Any hypernym for such vastly different things as *software, book*, and *car* will be mind-bogglingly vague and useless, by definition. I am curious: what ever do you need a mind-bogglingly vague and useless word for? You do realize its usefulness will be at the level of *thing* and *stuff*, because that's how little cars and books have in common? What is the exact scenario you are looking to use the word in? Please elaborate.

Comment: You have used the word you're looking for yourself:  *iteration*. When applied to designs and compositions, *iteration* implies design changes and refinements, not mere repetition.

Answer (score 1):

Not a generic term but how about 'remodeled'? I think it fits your way of defining. The verb 'remodel' means to model again, reconstruct or make over -

http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/remodel?s=t

The software/car gets remodeled every couple of years.

Whereas, I believe, a book really has editions *and* versions. Adaptations, translations, abridged, comic, children's, adults, etc. You can remodel the  cover of editions though - whether hard cover or paperback - in terms of size, graphic design, color and other physical components.

Comment: Also, things like story-plots can have versions. Not sure you can use 'remodel' there either but I don't think it sounds wrong to say 'a remodeled story-plot'.

Comment: Just saw this on meta stack exchange and perhaps you will like it better. The term is 'releases'. I picked it up on this page - http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/259220/new-navigation-alpha-2-released?cb=1. All things can have releases and there can be a current release.

Comment: maybe the reason we don't have a generic word for this quality is that _virtually everything we create_ can be edited, revisied, remodeled, refined, redefined, re-engineered, re-imagined....  The things we need a word for are the few things that are seemingly resistant or impervious to revision. In the short run, that includes such things as rocks and " human nature"; though in the long run these change as well—but gradually, not in perceptible increments.

Comment: @BrianHitchcock I heard that the Louvre is getting a new version of the Mona Lisa-  the previous one was getting too old.

Answer (score 1):

All things can change; organisms evolve, machines are improved, books and software are updated. Those that involve marketing,  *inventory* and/or *tooling* cannot be continuously improved. They must go through a *change cycle*, or, in other words, they are subject to *stepwise* improvement.

So I would call such things

- Stepwise {improvable/ changeable/ refinable/updatable. . . }

http://www.google.com/search?q=stepwise&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8&hl=en